# TypeScript Unexpected token, A constructor, method, accessor or property was expected. Error in IDE

Tags: typescript, vue.js, token, lifecycle, unexpected-token

I have this function it works as it should. But my Code Editor says: TypeScript Unexpected token, A constructor, method, accessor or property was expected.

```
  export default class ModalBase extends Vue {
    @Prop({ required: true }) readonly showCloseBUtton: boolean;
    
    @Emit () close() {}
    mounted () { 
        this.$nextTick().then(() => document.body.classList.add("has-overflow"));
        },
    
        destroyed () { 
        this.$nextTick().then(() => document.body.classList.add("has-overflow"));
        },
}
```

Comment: Hi, can you provide more info ? Like the code for the whole file, the context you are in and your setup (IDE, plugins, ....) And I guess 'moundet' and 'tehn' are typos, right ?

Comment: @Billuc 
Updated the Code. 
I use NeoVim. The function just triggers when the modal is opened or closed.

Comment: Ok I guess you are using `vue-class-component` and `vue-property-decorator`. Make sure you didn't forget the `@Component` before your `export default class` (I had a hard time finding that this was the problem sometimes). Also, make sure in your tsconfig file that decorators are enabled

Comment: Everything is set up as you said. But the error is still there.

Comment: Can you provide a repro, or more details about the code and your setup ? Right now it is very difficult to analyse the problem and find its cause

Comment: Found the solution. Our eslint would not accept a .then promise without a .catch(error)